# dynamically split an array of objects into groups based on values of a property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to **dynamically** split an array of objects into groups based on values of a property.

Here is an example of the input:

```
`input = [
    {"name": "john", "location": "first"},
    {"name": "steve", "location": "first"},
    {"name": "paul", "location": "another"},
    {"name": "tony", "location": "random"},
    {"name": "ant", "location": "random"}
]`
```

and the desired output:

```
`solution(input, location) = [
    first:   [{"name": "john", "location": "first"},
              {"name": "steve", "location": "first"}],
    another: [{"name": "paul", "location": "another"}],
    random:  [{"name": "tony", "location": "random"},
              {"name": "ant", "location": "random"}]
]`
```

I do not know the values that location can be (but i do know the key name)

I am trying to avoid using any external libs, 
(this is inside an angular 5 project)
but if it makes it drastically easier then I am not against it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `.concat(arr, arr2)`

Comment: @Karabah are you sure you read the question correctly ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that:

```js
const input = [{"name":"john","location":"first"},{"name":"steve","location":"first"},{"name":"paul","location":"another"},{"name":"tony","location":"random"},{"name":"ant","location":"random"}];

const group = input.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.location]) {
    acc[item.location] = [];
  }

  acc[item.location].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(group);
```

---

**Edit 1**

If you want to iterate on the result, you can use `for...of` loop with `Object.entries` like this:

```
for (let [location, persons] of Object.entries(group)) {
  console.log(location, persons);
  // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! that was super quick.. Ive been struggling to get my head round map and reduce but this has helped !

Comment: I have just noticed that the result of this answer is not an array but an object. I would like to create an array containing the result so I can iterate over it...