# Grouping a dynamic array object and forming a object required

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a dynamic object something like this

```
var object = [
    "70669",
    "70669|9436",
    "70669|8353",
    "70669|8914",
    "70669|9522",
    "70669|8422",
    "70669|9639"
    ]
```

My expected output is something like this

```
[{
    stdSizeCode: [9436, 8353, 8914, 9522, 8422, 9639]
    productHierSk: 70669
}]
```

I have tried to looking into [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045676/dynamically-split-an-array-of-objects-into-groups-based-on-values-of-a-property) and did not work the way that is expected. Can someone please suggest

Comment: What **specific** issue are you having?

Comment: If the input is `[ "1", "2|5", "1|2", "2" ]`, is the output `[ { stdSizeCode: [ 2 ], productHierSk: 1 }, { stdSizeCode: [ 5 ], productHierSk: 2 } ]`?

Comment: Hi @sebastian Simon : under unique product id different size codes as expected in an description

Comment: @SivaShanker Please _[edit]_ your question.

Comment: `object` is an array,

Comment: yes its an array

Comment: Yes @sebastian that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by with an object and get the values as result.

```js
const
    data = ["70669", "70669|9436", "70669|8353", "70669|8914", "70669|9522", "70669|8422", "70669|9639"],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, s) => {
        const [productHierSk, code] = s.split('|').map(Number);
        r[productHierSk] ??= { stdSizeCode: [], productHierSk };
        if (code !== undefined) r[productHierSk].stdSizeCode.push(code);
        return r;
    }, []));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: There is a typo. I think it should be `(code !== undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly

It work fine :

```js
var object = [
  "70669",
  "70669|9436",
  "70669|8353",
  "70669|8914",
  "70669|9522",
  "70669|8422",
  "70669|9639",
];

var result = [{ stdSizeCode: [], productHierSk: null }];

object.map((item) => {
  if (item.includes("|")) {
    result[0].stdSizeCode.push(parseInt(item.split("|")[1]));
  } else {
    result[0].productHierSk = parseInt(item);
  }
});

console.log("result : ", result);
```

Comment: [According to the OP](/questions/75548301/grouping-a-dynamic-array-object-and-forming-a-object-required/75548589#comment133290417_75548301), the input `[ "1", "2|5", "1|2", "2" ]` shall provide the output `[ { stdSizeCode: [ 2 ], productHierSk: 1 }, { stdSizeCode: [ 5 ], productHierSk: 2 } ]`. Your code assumes, there will only be a single distinct `productHierSk`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`split`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) together with the [destructuring assignment](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get both parts of each string.
Use [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert each substring to a number.
See [How to convert all elements in an array to integer in JavaScript?](/a/21644539/4642212).

The [`reduce`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call will iterate over your array and merge everything into a new [`Map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object.
The `Map` makes it easier to find and match your `productHierSk`s.
If you care about the order in which different `productHierSk`s occur in your `object`, you should use a `Map` instead of a plain object.

With [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) the `Map` is transformed into an Array of `[` *key* `,` *value* `]` pairs (in this case, the *key* is `productHierSk` and the *value* is the Array `stdSizeCode`).
One more `map` transforms each of these into the final object.

```js
const object1 = [
    "70669",
    "70669|9436",
    "70669|8353",
    "70669|8914",
    "70669|9522",
    "70669|8422",
    "70669|9639"
  ],
  object2 = [
    "1",
    "2|5",
    "1|2",
    "2"
  ];

const getSizeCodes = (object) => Array.from(object.reduce((stdSizeCodes, string) => {
    const [
        productHierSk,
        stdSizeCode
      ] = string.split("|").map(Number);

    if(!stdSizeCodes.has(productHierSk)){
      stdSizeCodes.set(productHierSk, []);
    }

    if(stdSizeCode){
      stdSizeCodes.get(productHierSk).push(stdSizeCode);
    }

    return stdSizeCodes;
  }, new Map()).entries())
    .map(([ productHierSk, stdSizeCode ]) => ({
      productHierSk,
      stdSizeCode
    }));

console.log(getSizeCodes(object1));
console.log(getSizeCodes(object2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```